# Ability to select line items from report results to create another report \ subreport

Tags: reporting-services

We have a report built that accepts 5 or 6 parameters, it then produces the report as expected. What we would like to do at this point is be able to select (by check box perhaps?) specific line items in the report and submit (Submit button?) these items for a new report. I understand we could simply modify or add more parameters but for whatever reason, the "need" is to be able to select from the report results.

is this even possible?

Thanks all

Comment: Which version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: What is the source of the data - a SQL Server database?  If so then this is possible.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 pulling from a SQL database....sorry for delay in response , I need to see if I can setup email notification for comments

Comment: Nothing else...anyone?